# Criteria query using projections to get only property value?

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate. i have an entity class called XYZ. it has 10 properties. but i need only one property(one column) which of Integer type to be retrieved and returned.

it should be like:

```
public Integer getxyz(String someName){
}
```

but not:

```
public XYZ getxyz(String someName){
}
```

//i have to return only the property value that i have mapped . not the entity class with one property.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question? You know that you have to use a projection, so do it. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one property to be retrieved and saved, do not map other properties at all.

If you only need to load a single column from the table, don't use the `XYZ` object at all - write HQL or Criteria query in your DAO which retrieves that raw number (or list of these numbers).

Comment: Coiuld you provide examples of such HQL and Criteria solutions?